# How to use environment variable in apache config condition?

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, apache2, docker-compose

In my apache config file I'm trying to set a virtual host on port 443 IF my environment variable is not `dev`

I have a docker container running via docker-compose which specifies the environment variables.

To check the env variables are properly set, I remote into my container:

```
root@4f212c1c7e23:/var/www# echo ${APP_ENV}
prod
```

Below is the apache config file that is apart of the volume mapped to the container

`000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName ${DOMAIN}
  ServerAdmin ${ADMIN_EMAIL}
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule "%{APP_ENV} != 'dev'">
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

      ServerName ${DOMAIN}
      ServerAdmin ${ADMIN_EMAIL}
      DocumentRoot /var/www/public
            
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
      SSLCertificateFile /var/imported/ssl/main.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/imported/ssl/privkey.pem
      SSLEngine on

    </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But when starting the container on production, the result in browser is "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" when trying to access port 443.

My error log only reads:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Similarly the expression `"%{APP_ENV} == 'prod'"`, gives the same result

When deleting the outer `IfModule` in the apache config, the connection is accepted and everything works as expected.

So I'm wondering how to get the outer `IfModule` condition to behave as intended?

Please let me know if there is more info I can provide

Comment: I realize that `IfModule` is not doing what I think it does. I have instead opted to use `IfFile` which checks if main.crt exists (which is only copied in my production docker-compose file): `<IfFile "/var/imported/ssl/main.crt">` and this seems to work as I planned